# Registering assembly for Interop assembly with COM visible interfaces only gives warning MSB3214

Tags: c#, com, com-interop

I have a project with a single interface marked with ComVisible(true).  If I build the project, I get warning MSB3214: "" does not contain any types that can be registered for COM Interop.

If, however, I create an empty class, give it a default constructor and mark it with ComVisible(true), I do not get warning MSB3214.  I see the registered class but I do not see the interface in my registry.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design, in spite of Jays link.  Regasm.exe only writes registry keys for concrete classes that implement an interface.  The ProgID and the CLSID keys.  COM does have registration for interfaces (HKCR\Interfaces) but only proxies get registered there.  .NET has no mechanism to create proxies.

An assembly with *only* interface declarations is only useful to create a type library, allowing other projects to implement them.  Creating a type library is not a problem, use Tlbexp.exe

Comment: So, does this mean I can registry type library with Tlbexp?

Comment: There is also no need to register type libraries that contain no concrete COM classes.  What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I have interfaces that will be called from C++.  I was trying to allow these interfaces to be implemented by concrete classes whether or not they are exposed to COM.  I ended up just putting interface in my COM wrapper DLL>   Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it could be a Visual Studio 2008 bug reported in July 2008: [VS creates no type library for a project containing solely C# interfaces (MSB3214)](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/355505/vs-creates-no-type-library-for-a-project-containing-solely-c-interfaces-msb3214#details)

There are no listed workarounds.

In a response data Sept 2009 Microsoft they were (presumably) able to fix the issue:

> We were able to fix this issue and the
>   bug will be available in the next
>   release of the product.

(let's assume he meant the bug ***fix*** will be available in the next release)

I couldn't find any evidence the bug was fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Let me investigate alternative suggested by Hans P.